# Access denied when accessing an AWS bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a video in an aws bucket that I want to access. So, I'm clicking on the object uri which is the following:
https://humboi-videos.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4
However, in the xml that's presented, I'm getting an Access Denied error. How to fix this error, and how to access the video with a single url?

Comment: unless bucket is made publicly accessible, any objects in S3 bucket will not be accessible  publicly via direct url. we can programmatically provide access to objects via [pre-signed urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763592/i-get-nosuchkey-error-after-generating-presigned-url/65763951#65763951)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the console you must click "Download" which will generate a pre-signed-url which you can use to download the file.
You can make the file "Public" by clicking on the item in S3, click "Object Actions" and then "Make Public.
This will make the file available to everybody on the internet - I am not sure if this is what you want?

Otherwise, you would have to programmatically generate pre-signed URLs to access the files using secure links.